# KnockoutJs - How to throttle the binding afterkeydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mvvm, knockout.js

I got this working for my filtering functionality.

```
<input data-bind="value: filterByName, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" />
 <div data-bind="foreach: filteredRecords"/>
</body>
```

Now i just need to `throttle` the binding of the `filteredRecords` or  to put delay on it

my view model looks like this

```
 self.filteredRecords= ko.computed(function () {
        return getRecordByStatus(1);
    });

 self.filterByName= ko.observable("");


 var getRecordByStatus = function (status) {

            var periodRecord, filtered = [];

            if (self.timesheetApprovalResponse().periods) {
                // period filtering
                if (self.selectedPeriod()) {
                    periodRecord = _.find(self.timesheetApprovalResponse().periods, function(p) {
                        return p.fromDate === self.selectedPeriod().key;
                    });

                    if (periodRecord) {
                        filtered = _.where(periodRecord.timesheets,
                            function(t) {
                                return t.status === status;
                            });
                    }
                }
            }

            if (self.filterByName()) {
                filtered = _.where(filtered,
                    function (t) {


                        console.log(t.name.toLowerCase() + "-" + self.filterByName().toLowerCase());
                        return t.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.filterByName().toLowerCase()) > -1;
                    });
            }


            return filtered;
        };
```

Now my problem is where to put the `.extend({ throttle: 500 });`
I think I cannot put it on `filteredRecords` as it will also throttle in `Page Load` ?

Any other ideas?

Comment: If I understand what you are after, then you probably want to throttle `filterByName`.  This will prevent `filteredRecords` from being notified until `filterByName` stops changing for x milliseconds.

Comment: Yep! thats all i need to do! if you provide it as an answer ill mark it down.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are after, then you probably want to throttle `filterByName`. This will prevent `filteredRecords` from being notified until `filterByName` stops changing for x milliseconds.